# How to view MySQL processes that uses most CPU?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, innodb, cpu-usage

Is any way to check which MySQL processes overloads CPU in real time ? Like `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` , but with CPU live usage.
I am running Centos with CWP.
10.1.45-MariaDB

Comment: From OS Command Prompt, htop or top would likely give you the PID (process id) and CPU % when requested and then find query in the SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; report.

Comment: Well here is top stats: https://ibb.co/xqNzTtJ , and here sql full process list: https://ibb.co/wYZpVFH

Comment: Use the slowlog to get the info after the queries finish.  If you are saturating the CPU, then you need help with indexes or query formulation.

Comment: After several hours of slowlog enabled log file seems empty. Mysql load still persists 450%. Maybe it is normal ? On 6 cores 16 gb ram i am running 9 wordpress sites.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a Linux/Unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis & provide suggestions to get slow log active .

Comment: "with Kill going on?" - this is Kill button. I just upgraded server to 8 cores/30Gb ram/800Gb SSD. Getting now 450-600% cpu load. Well , what about findfragtables.sql - i have no clue how to use it. Adittional info  - B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; - https://pastebin.com/U5KE9WnA | C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; - https://pastebin.com/BQYycaSu  | D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; - https://pastebin.com/XyvDrUXc | - ulimit -a - https://pastebin.com/HRg4rgjj | iostat -xm 5 3 - https://pastebin.com/HKbhuXrC |  df -h - https://pastebin.com/NW0NjuZw

Comment: To use findfragtables.sql script, you should have received email with link to download the script.  Save the script to your working folder of xxxx.sql scripts, from MySQL Client Command Prompt, execute the script and a list of fragmented tables will be created with the 'worst' listed first.  Attach the TEXT output to email to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com for complimentary feedback of our observations.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section  (could be change or add line)

```
log_error=/var/log/vmi223365.err  # to name file for errors (do not fly blind)
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain  # for more useful slow query log
slow_query_log=OFF  # until you get your slow_queries RPS well under 23 RPS
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to use more of your available SSD capacity
read_buffer_size=1M  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 1,000,658
```

When you will want to log Slow Queries, from MySQL Command Prompt,
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=ON;     for 15 minutes and you will have plenty of items
and after 15 minutes
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=OFF;    to avoid just wasting cpu cycles and storage all day.

Your slow_queries count of 1,714,470 in 21 hours indicates many indexes are needed.

For additional suggestions, view profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts.